# How to enable button Angular JS if file was selected?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I use this [library](https://github.com/nervgh/angular-file-upload) for uploading files in Angular JS.

How can I enable submit button if file was selected?

I can get access to object:

```
var uploader = new FileUploader({})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just check the length of `queue` property - this is an array with selected file(s).

JS:

```
$scope.uploader = new FileUploader({});
```

HTML:

```
<button type="button" ng-disabled="uploader.queue.length < 1">Upload</button>
```

**UPDATE**

this is how you can check how many files were loaded:

JS:

`var loaded = $filter('filter')($scope.uploader.queue, {isUploaded: true})`

or show it in your template:

`<span ng-bind="(uploader.queue | filter: {isUploaded: true}).length"></span>`

**UPDATE 2**

to enable button if at least one file has been uploaded:

```
<button type="button" ng-disabled="(uploader.queue | filter: {isUploaded: true}).length < 1">Do something</button>
```

Comment: And how to check how much files were loaded?

Comment: Updated the answer. Check module API also, it has a lot of useful info you can use
https://github.com/nervgh/angular-file-upload/wiki/Module-API

Comment: Where user `loaded` in template?